C# ASP.NET Core 8 Identity - can't use methods with role authorize attribute
I am building a project with a custom UserRoleStore, implementing methods from these interfaces:

IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>
IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>
IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>

To auth, I use JwtBearer.
I create my token using this method
public string GenerateToken(ApplicationUser user, IList<string> roles, bool rememberMe)
{
    var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                         {
                             new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),  // User ID
                             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),      // User Name
                             new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),        // Email
                             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) // Token ID

                             // new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id.ToString()),
                             // new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                             // new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName),
                             // new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
                         };

    authClaims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

    var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretKey));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _issuer,
        audience: _audience,
        expires: rememberMe ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(7) : DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
        claims: authClaims,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha384)
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

Auth is done using this controller:
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("login")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(AuthResultModel))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequestModel request)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Password))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var result = await _accountService.LoginAsync(request.Email, request.Password, request.RememberMe);

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            return Unauthorized(result.Errors);
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}

And this service:
public async Task<AuthResultModel> LoginAsync(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        if (user == null || !await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
        {
            return new AuthResultModel { Success = false, Errors = new List<string> { "Invalid email or password" } };
        }

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        var token = _jwtService.GenerateToken(user, roles, rememberMe);

        return new AuthResultModel
        {
            Success = true,
            Token = token,
            UserId = user.Id,
            Role = roles.FirstOrDefault().Normalize() 
        };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, $"Failed to login for user: {email}.\n {e.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

I log in, I got a token, paste it into Authorization header like this: Bearer {token}.
I am trying to use method with [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] attribute via Swagger and Postman and I am getting 401/403 errors.
This is how I configured auth in my Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
    .AddUserStore<UserRoleStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
            RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Development",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
});
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

I tried different claims. I tried the test method with debug and there is ClaimsPrincipal object with every claim, that I put into token. But my method with auth attribute still results in a 401/403 error

Try removing : [AllowAnonymous]

@jdweng doesnt work. Receiving 403 error.

Are y ou getting any messages in the logger?

I logged every code block and investigated it. So the problem that I had: was that in the database there was the same name as the role in JWT Token, but it doesn't recognize them as the same. I deleted the role, and published the database again - and it works
